# Dynamic Table in Angular JS from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, dynamic

I am trying to generate a dynamic table from Angular JS by receiving a response from Spring Rest Service.

This is my code:

```js
// JavaScript Document

var app = angular.module("SDLC", []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }]);

var urlBase = "http://localhost:8080";

app.controller('projecttable_controller', function($scope, $http) {
  
  $scope.ordered_columns = [];
  $scope.all_columns = [{
    "title": "Project Name",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "title": "Project Description",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "title": "Owner",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "title": "Start Date",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "title": "End Date",
    "type": "string"
  },{
    "title": "Record ID",
    "type": "string"
  }];
  

  $http.get(urlBase+'/hello?input=raina').
     success(function(data) {
  //alert(data); 
  $scope.data=data; 
  alert($scope.data);
  });
  
  
  $scope.$watch('all_columns', function() {
    update_columns();
  }, true);

  var update_columns = function() {
    $scope.ordered_columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.all_columns.length; i++) {
      var column = $scope.all_columns[i];
        $scope.ordered_columns.push(column);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-box-row row-fluid">
                                 <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th ng-repeat="c in ordered_columns">{{ c.title }}
                                        </th>
                                      </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="ds in data">
                                          <td ng-repeat="c in ordered_columns">{{ d[c.title] }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </div>
```

There are no errors in the console. The table headers are displayed correctly. However, the data does not get populated in the table. If I hardcode the json in $scope.data, the table gets populated properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you get your response data and you place it in "$scope.data" and that is where it always stays

Comment: change `<tr ng-repeat="ds in data">` to `<tr ng-repeat="d in data">`,  seems to be typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch your GET response, you write `$scope.data = data;` and you do nothing with `$scope.data`

change:

```
 $http.get(urlBase+'/hello?input=raina').
     success(function(data) {
        //alert(data);  
        $scope.data=data; 
        alert($scope.data);
     });
```

to:

```
 $http.get(urlBase+'/hello?input=raina').
     success(function(data) {
        //alert(data);  
        $scope.all_columns=data; 
        alert($scope.data);
     });
```

Because I see you populate your table from $scope.all_columns